# Spring Boot SAML problems using reverse proxy

Tags: spring-boot, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have a problem with the following scenario: multiple back-end servers process SAML requests forwarded by a reverse-proxy.

I tried to configure the contextProvider as follow: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-load-balancing

This is my SAML configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OsiApplication.class);

    private static final String PROTOCOL = "https";

    private static final String BINDING = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST";

    @Value("${saml.metadata-file}")
    private String metadataFile;

    @Value("${saml.idp-selection-path}")
    private String idpSelectionPath;

    @Value("${saml.openmind-app-id}")
    private String openmindAppId;

    @Value("${saml.success-redirect}")
    private String successRedirect;

    @Value("${saml.failure-redirect}")
    private String failureRedirect;

    @Value("${saml.lb-server-name}")
    private String lbServerName;

    @Value("${saml.lb-scheme}")
    private String lbScheme;

    @Value("${saml.lb-context-path}")
    private String lbContextPath;

    @Value("${saml.lb-server-port}")
    private int lbServerPort;

    @Value("${saml.lb-include-port}")
    private boolean lbIncludePort;

    @Value("${saml.store-path}")
    private String storePath;

    @Value("${saml.store-pass}")
    private String storePass;

    @Value("${saml.store-default-key}")
    private String storeDefaultKey;

    @Value("${saml.secured}")
    private boolean secured;

    @Value("${application.admin-code}")
    private String adminCode;

    @Value("${application.user-code}")
    private String userCode;

    @Autowired
    private SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl samlUserDetailsServiceImpl;

    private Timer backgroundTaskTimer;

    private MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.backgroundTaskTimer = new Timer(true);
        this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        this.backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
        this.backgroundTaskTimer.cancel();
        this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.shutdown();
    }



    // Initialization of the velocity engine
    // XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing
    @Bean(initMethod = "initialize")
    public StaticBasicParserPool parserPool() {
        return new StaticBasicParserPool();
    }

    @Bean(name = "parserPoolHolder")
    public ParserPoolHolder parserPoolHolder() {
        return new ParserPoolHolder();
    }

    // Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages
    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        return new HttpClient(this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager);
    }

    // SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML
    // messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
        SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider = new SAMLAuthenticationProvider();
        samlAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetails(samlUserDetailsServiceImpl);
        samlAuthenticationProvider.setForcePrincipalAsString(false);
        return samlAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    // Provider of default SAML Context
    @Bean
    public SAMLContextProviderLB contextProvider() {
        // This error may occur during SP-initiated SSO. A SAML authn request is sent to the IdP and a
        // SAML response is returned. We check that the InResponseTo field in the SAML response matches
        // the ID field of the authn request.
        // If they don't match then we throw the error you see
        // FIX This can be done by setting DisableInResponseToCheck to true in the <PartnerIdentityProvider> entry in your saml.config.
        SAMLContextProviderLB sAMLContextProviderImpl = new SAMLContextProviderLB();
        // configuration of reverse proxy of saml
        sAMLContextProviderImpl.setServerName(lbServerName);
        sAMLContextProviderImpl.setScheme(lbScheme);
        sAMLContextProviderImpl.setContextPath(lbContextPath);
        sAMLContextProviderImpl.setServerPort(lbServerPort);
        sAMLContextProviderImpl.setIncludeServerPortInRequestURL(false);
        /*EmptyStorageFactory emptyStorageFactory = new EmptyStorageFactory();
        sAMLContextProviderImpl.setStorageFactory(emptyStorageFactory);*/
        return sAMLContextProviderImpl;
    }

    // Initialization of OpenSAML library
    @Bean
    public static SAMLBootstrap sAMLBootstrap() {
        return new SAMLBootstrap();
    }

    // Logger for SAML messages and events
    @Bean
    public SAMLDefaultLogger samlLogger() {
        return new SAMLDefaultLogger();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumer webSSOprofileConsumer() {
        WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl webSSOProfileConsumer = new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
        webSSOProfileConsumer.setMaxAuthenticationAge(28800);
        return webSSOProfileConsumer;
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOprofileConsumer() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfile webSSOprofile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOProfile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 ECP profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileECPImpl ecpprofile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileECPImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public SingleLogoutProfile logoutprofile() {
        return new SingleLogoutProfileImpl();
    }

    // Central storage of cryptographic keys
    @Bean
    public KeyManager keyManager() {
        DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader(); 
        Resource storeFile = loader
                .getResource(storePath);

        String defaultKey = storeDefaultKey;
        Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<>();
        passwords.put(defaultKey, storePass);

        return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
    }

    // Setup TLS Socket Factory
    @Bean
    public TLSProtocolConfigurer tlsProtocolConfigurer() {
        return new TLSProtocolConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public ProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory() {
        return new TLSProtocolSocketFactory(keyManager(), null, "default");
    }

    @Bean
    public Protocol socketFactoryProtocol() {
        return new Protocol(PROTOCOL, socketFactory(), 443);
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodInvokingFactoryBean socketFactoryInitialization() {
        MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(Protocol.class);
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("registerProtocol");
        Object[] args = { PROTOCOL, socketFactoryProtocol() };
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(args);
        return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileOptions defaultWebSSOProfileOptions() {
        WebSSOProfileOptions webSSOProfileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
        webSSOProfileOptions.setIncludeScoping(false);
        webSSOProfileOptions.setBinding(BINDING);
        return webSSOProfileOptions;
    }

    // Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from
    // properties file
    @Bean
    public SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint() {
        SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint = new SAMLEntryPoint();
        samlEntryPoint.setDefaultProfileOptions(defaultWebSSOProfileOptions());
        return samlEntryPoint;
    }

    // Setup advanced info about metadata
    @Bean
    public ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata() {
        ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
        extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(false);
        extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(true); 
        extendedMetadata.setEcpEnabled(false);
        return extendedMetadata;
    }

    // IDP Discovery Service
    @Bean
    public SAMLDiscovery samlIDPDiscovery() {
        SAMLDiscovery idpDiscovery = new SAMLDiscovery();
        idpDiscovery.setIdpSelectionPath(idpSelectionPath);
        return idpDiscovery;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("idp-ssocircle")
    public ExtendedMetadataDelegate ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider()
            throws MetadataProviderException {
        File file = null;
        String metadata = metadataFile;
        DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();

        try {
            file = loader.getResource(metadata).getFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("IOException => {}", e);
        }

        FilesystemMetadataProvider filesystemMetadataProvider = new FilesystemMetadataProvider(file);
        filesystemMetadataProvider.setRequireValidMetadata(true);
        filesystemMetadataProvider.setParserPool(new BasicParserPool());
        filesystemMetadataProvider.initialize();

        //
        ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
        extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(false);
        extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(true);

        ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate = new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(filesystemMetadataProvider, extendedMetadata());
        extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);
        extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);

        return extendedMetadataDelegate;
    }

    // IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust
    // is here
    // Do no forget to call initalize method on providers
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("metadata")
    public CachingMetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException {
        List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<>();
        providers.add(ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider());
        return new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
    }

    // Filter automatically generates default SP metadata
    @Bean
    public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
        MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
        metadataGenerator.setEntityId(openmindAppId);
        metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata());
        metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(false);
        metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager());
        metadataGenerator.setEntityBaseURL(successRedirect);
        return metadataGenerator;
    }

    // The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix
    // and presents SP metadata there
    @Bean
    public MetadataDisplayFilter metadataDisplayFilter() {
        return new MetadataDisplayFilter();
    }

    // Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login
    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(successRedirect);
        return successRedirectHandler;
    }

    // Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl(failureRedirect);
        return simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    }

    @Bean
    public SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter = new SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter();
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter;
    }

    // Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter() {
        return new MetadataGeneratorFilter(metadataGenerator());
    }

    // Handler for successful logout
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler() {
        SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler = new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler();
        successLogoutHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(lbContextPath);
        return successLogoutHandler;
    }

    // Logout handler terminating local session
    @Bean
    public SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler() {
        SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
        logoutHandler.setInvalidateHttpSession(true);
        logoutHandler.setClearAuthentication(true);
        return logoutHandler;
    }

    // Filter processing incoming logout messages
    // First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful
    // global logout
    @Bean
    public SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter samlLogoutProcessingFilter() {
        return new SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
                logoutHandler());
    }

    // Overrides default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML
    // messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLLogoutFilter samlLogoutFilter() {
        return new SAMLLogoutFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
                new LogoutHandler[] { logoutHandler() },
                new LogoutHandler[] { logoutHandler() });
    }

    // Bindings
    private ArtifactResolutionProfile artifactResolutionProfile() {
        final ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl artifactResolutionProfile = new ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl(httpClient());
        artifactResolutionProfile.setProcessor(new SAMLProcessorImpl(soapBinding()));
        return artifactResolutionProfile;
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPArtifactBinding artifactBinding(ParserPool parserPool, VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
        return new HTTPArtifactBinding(parserPool, velocityEngine, artifactResolutionProfile());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding soapBinding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPPostBinding httpPostBinding() {
        return new HTTPPostBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding httpRedirectDeflateBinding() {
        return new HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding httpSOAP11Binding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPPAOS11Binding httpPAOS11Binding() {
        return new HTTPPAOS11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    // Processor
    @Bean
    public SAMLProcessorImpl processor() {
        Collection<SAMLBinding> bindings = new ArrayList<>();
        bindings.add(httpRedirectDeflateBinding());
        bindings.add(httpPostBinding());
        bindings.add(artifactBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine()));
        bindings.add(httpSOAP11Binding());
        bindings.add(httpPAOS11Binding());
        return new SAMLProcessorImpl(bindings);
    }

    @Bean
    public VelocityEngine velocityEngine() {
        return VelocityFactory.getEngine();
    }

    /**
     * Define the security filter chain in order to support SSO Auth by using SAML 2.0
     * 
     * @return Filter chain proxy
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean
    public FilterChainProxy samlFilter() throws Exception {
        List<SecurityFilterChain> chains = new ArrayList<>();
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/login/**"),
                samlEntryPoint()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout/**"),
                samlLogoutFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/metadata/**"),
                metadataDisplayFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"),
                samlWebSSOProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSOHoK/**"),
                samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SingleLogout/**"),
                samlLogoutProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/discovery/**"),
                samlIDPDiscovery()));
        return new FilterChainProxy(chains);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the authentication manager currently used by Spring. It represents a bean definition with the aim allow wiring from other classes performing the Inversion of Control (IoC).
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
       return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    /**
     * Defines the web based security configuration.
     * 
     * @param http
     *            It allows configuring web based security for specific http requests.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      /*http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);*/
      http
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http
                .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                //.permitAll();
                .authenticated();

        http
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");

        http
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    /**
     * Sets a custom authentication provider.
     * 
     * @param auth
     *            SecurityBuilder used to create an AuthenticationManager.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());
    }
```

and this is my configuration file

```
saml.metadata-file= metadata.xml
saml.idp-selection-path= /osi/saml/login?idp=IDP
saml.openmind-app-id= com:na:app:local:dev
saml.success-redirect= https://localhost:4200/context
saml.success= https://localhost:4200/#/files
saml.failure-redirect= https://localhost:4200/#/error
saml.lb-server-name= localhost:4200
saml.lb-scheme= https
saml.lb-context-path= /context
saml.lb-server-port= 4200
saml.lb-include-port= true
saml.store-path= classpath:localhost.jks
saml.store-pass= pass
saml.store-default-key= 1
saml.secured= true
```

While trying to login the authentification failes:
INFO o.s.s.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger - AuthNResponse;FAILURE;100.83.63.69;com:na:app:local:dev;IDP;;;org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message a87hdee46ffejbd317h793f719g64h

Answer (score 1):

adding a web.xml file to the project with the  tag solved the issues

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
                              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
    <distributable />
    <!-- ... -->
</web-app>
```